# Build ffmpeg under Cygwin: Invalid relocation. Offset at address doesn't fit into 32 bits

Tags: ffmpeg, cygwin

Trying to build **ffmpeg-5.1** under **Cygwin**, "*natively*" i.e to be dependant under the cygwin DLL, not necessarily cross-compiling for pure Windows.

I built separately a lot of the dependant libs.
Some of the libs were provided by the cygwin repo naturally.

```
[ /usr/local/src/ffmpeg-5.1]λ ./configure --disable-shared --enable-static --extra-cflags="-I/usr/local/include" --extra-ldflags="-L/usr/local/lib" --enable-gpl --enable-nonfree --enable-openssl --enable-gcrypt --enable-libass --enable-libcaca --enable-libcelt --enable-libcdio --enable-libdav1d --enable-libfdk-aac --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-libgsm --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-libsoxr --enable-libssh --enable-libtheora --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxvid --enable-libxml2 --enable-libzmq --enable-pic --disable-avdevice

install prefix            /usr/local
source path               .
C compiler                gcc
C library                 newlib
ARCH                      x86 (generic)
big-endian                no
runtime cpu detection     yes
standalone assembly       yes
x86 assembler             nasm
MMX enabled               yes
MMXEXT enabled            yes
3DNow! enabled            yes
3DNow! extended enabled   yes
SSE enabled               yes
SSSE3 enabled             yes
AESNI enabled             yes
AVX enabled               yes
AVX2 enabled              yes
AVX-512 enabled           yes
AVX-512ICL enabled        yes
XOP enabled               yes
FMA3 enabled              yes
FMA4 enabled              yes
i686 features enabled     yes
CMOV is fast              yes
EBX available             yes
EBP available             yes
debug symbols             yes
strip symbols             yes
optimize for size         no
optimizations             yes
static                    yes
shared                    no
postprocessing support    yes
network support           yes
threading support         pthreads
safe bitstream reader     yes
texi2html enabled         no
perl enabled              yes
pod2man enabled           yes
makeinfo enabled          yes
makeinfo supports HTML    yes
xmllint enabled           yes

...
```

```
[ /usr/local/src/ffmpeg-5.1]λ ./ffmpeg -version
Cygwin runtime failure: /usr/local/src/ffmpeg-5.1/ffmpeg.exe: Invalid relocation.  Offset 0x7ffd7778b627 at address 0x100a92895 doesn't fit into 32 bits
```

Suggestions for build options / root cause?

Comment: I think your build process has created one or `.dll` shared libraries. In cygwin, these need to be `rebased` along with all the other shared libraries used by cygwin. Use `https://www.google.com/search?q=site%3Acygwin.com+Invalid+relocation` to find relevant answers, especially see some of the emails about `xpdf`

Comment: to go Windows natively you should use the cross-compiler `x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc.exe` for mingw target, not try to force the Cygwin compiler to do it.

Comment: @DougHenderson, did a `/usr/bin/rebase-trigger full`, reboot, re-ran cygwin setup, `rebaseall`, rebuilt ffmpeg, got same error!

Comment: When i had a similar problem, I installed the `xz` src package and looked at how the library dll is built by the `makefile(s)`. This uses the `cygport` facility to build the cygwin packages which will build the library and any exes. See also src pkgs for `zstd` and `xxhash`.

Comment: Have you tried `https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=ffmpeg+cygwin`.